# Latest Opera browser renders jagged edges on font

Tags: html, css, fonts, opera

I'm testing my website in Opera, browser version 24.0 on Windows 7. The font I'm using is 'fira sans'.

The font renders nicely in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer however in Opera, it renders horribly with jagged edges.

I'm using Google fonts as the hosting service and I have read that there are issues with some fonts from there.

I have tried applying `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`. It makes no difference.

I've done a quick test and it seems that if I download the font and use the `@fontace` rule, it works much better. I would much rather use the font hosting service that Google provides than use @fontace though.

Does anyone know of any other possible solutions? I've been told that Opera isn't really considered as a big deal but I do want my site looking good in all browsers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `text-shadow` like this: http://www.icondeposit.com/blog:how-to-properly-smooth-font-using-css3

Answer (score 0):

Opera 25 has some dispay issues on Windows. Did you try to disable Direct Write in Opera 25 with opera://flags/#disable-direct-write.
Dont forget to restart Opera after this new setting.